# Pass multiple parameters with different types using $.ajax to an MVC method

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having some problems posting multiple parameters to my controller using AJAX.I want to pass model list and button name (string) to my controller.

jQuery:

```
function PostForm(buttonname) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/ControllerName/ViewName",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "application/JSON",
        data: 
        JSON.stringify({ 
           listOfObjects = $('#form').serialize(),
           button : buttonname
        })
    });
};
```

partial view:

```
<input name="buttonname" value="Name" onClick="PostForm('Name')" />
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewName(List<MyObject> listOfObjects ,string button)
{
//Obj should now contain the list of objects and button name
}
```

On click of button,i am getting the value of button name but count of listobjects is 0.

How do I pass multiple params with different datatypes to the MVC method?

Ideas and suggestions greatly appreciated !
Thanks!

Comment: can you show your #form, also MyObject, check on fiddler which query do you send and post here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
function PostForm(buttonname) {

var data = $('#form').serialize();
var finaldata = data + "&buttonclicked="+buttonname;

$.ajax({
    url: "/ControllerName/ViewName",
    type: "POST",
    data: finaldata ,
    success: success function(){},
    error : error function(){}
    });
};
```

partial view:

```
<input name="buttonname" value="Name" onClick="PostForm('Name')" />
```

Controller:

[HttpPost]

```
public ActionResult ViewName(List<MyObject> listOfObjects ,string buttonclicked)
{
//Obj should now contain the list of objects and button name
}
```

the problem was i was using same name for button's name and input paramtere of the POST method in controller.Thats why i was getting list of all the button's names.
Neways its working now..

thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

function PostForm(buttonname) {

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ControllerName/ViewName",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "application/JSON",
    data: JSON.stringify($('#form').serialize())
});
```

};

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewName(FormCollection formCollection)
{
     // use formCollection["yourcontrol"] to get your post value
}
```

Comment: i am having a grid which contains buttons.so i wont be able to find the post value of it using formcollection[].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

View:

```
function PostForm(buttonname) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/ControllerName/ViewName",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "application/JSON",
        data: { listOfObjects: data: $('#Form').serilize(), button: buttonname },
        JSON.stringify({ 
           listOfObjects = $('#form').serialize(),
           button : buttonname
        })
    });
};
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewName(MyObject[] listOfObjects ,string button)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

form.serialize() works alone. With additional data, It does not work. 
remove `dataType` and try like this:

```
data: $('#Form').serilize() + "&button=" + buttonname
```

hope it helps.

Comment: sorry... i was using the same name as button's name.Getting the values now.